# Can I reload my page in Blazor without using the NavigationManager.NavigateTo forceLoad option?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor (server-side) page and on a given event I want to reload the page (i.e. with the OnInitialized/OnInitializedAsync functions called again).

The standard way to do this is calling `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.Uri, true)`, but the `forceLoad = true` option trigger a full browser refresh, with the user being logged out because the authentication token is stored on the browser session storage, and then he needs to login again which I don't want.

On the other hand, if I set `forceLoad = false` then this is not a real page reload (i.e. the OnInitialized/OnInitializedAsync functions are not called again) because the URL didn't change.

So the only working solution I found is calling `NavigateTo` two times in a row, as follow:

```cs
string url = NavManager.Uri;
NavManager.NavigateTo("/fake-page", false); // Note: this is a dirty trick just to force the page reload without the user being logged-out
NavManager.NavigateTo(url, false);
```

But surely there is a cleaner way to achieve that?

Comment: What are you doint within the `OnInitialized` method? You can use the `OnParametersSetAsync` event to achieve a repeated execution of your code.

Comment: @Marvin Klein I'm doing on `OnInitialized` some pretty heavy computations that I only want to occur at the first loading of the page and not on every parameter changes, and moreover `OnParametersSetAsync` is not called again if I call `NavManager.NavigateTo(url, false)` so it cannot be a solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tested with "Counter" page. Call `OnInitializedAsync` directly doesn't clear the session.

```
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedSessionStorage ProtectedSessionStore
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="refresh">refresh</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var result = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<int>("count");
        currentCount = result.Success ? result.Value : 0;
    }

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        await ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("count", currentCount);
    }

    private async Task refresh()
    {
        OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right! My user disconnection was not due to the session storage being cleared, as I wrongly assumed, but by a bug in the application authentication logic that I just found out.

Comment: Note that in your exemple you could replace the `OnInitializedAsync()` call with `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.Uri, true)` and it will also work.